# Rollback Visual Studio Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, version-control, restore

I want to know, if possible, how to roolback an application created using visual studio.
Imagining that I have released version 1.0.0 above, yesterday I made some changes to the .cs file and I released a new version 1.0.1.
Now I would like to restore the version 1.0.0 and .cs files of that version in the meantime they have been overwritten by the updated.
The only thing I see refer to version 1.0.0 are the .application, .manifest, and .deploy files within the Application Files folder but they can not trace the source files (.cs).
Is there a solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance and sorry for the imperfect English

Comment: Sadly now it is too late to roll back, but to be able to do so in the future, look at vivek nuna's answer.

Comment: If you haven't used some kind of [Version Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system and you don't have any backup of your previous version the last tool at your disposition is your memory

Comment: [Decompiling](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) your old version might work too, but always use version control afterwards

Answer (score 4):

You should use Source Version Control tools like Git or SVN to keep track of your project history.